# How can handle multiple " ' in twig template?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I am using twig and symfony2.
I want to use this sentence in twig

```
onmouseover='this.src="{{ asset("bundles/acmetop/images/room/btn_volum_on.png") }}"'
```

I tried some patterns but it never works:

- `onmouseover='this.src="{{ asset(\"bundles/acmetop/images/room/btn_volum_on.png\") }}"'`
- `onmouseover='this.src=\"{{ asset("bundles/acmetop/images/room/btn_volum_on.png") }}\"'`

But, I get the error:

```
Unexpected character "\" in AcmeRoomBundle:Default:index.html.twig
```

How can handle multiple `"` and `'` in a twig template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this instead:

```
onmouseover="this.src='{{ asset("bundles/acmetop/images/room/btn_volum_on.png") }}';"
```

It will output as something like:

```
onmouseover="this.src='/bundles/acmetop/images/room/btn_volum_on.png';"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! its really nice and simple answer.it works well!